# Get Google Hangout meeting room information

Tags: google-hangouts

Anyone know if its possible to get information of a Google Hangout meeting room. ie. get participants, or number of participants currently in room?

I would like to load that information and print it on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the methods on hangouts api docs [here](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout#functions), you can fetch any data you want, say participants list, hangout url etc.